# ./components/Layout/Navbar.js Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'next/link' (imported as 'Link')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

/components/Layout/Navbar.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'next/link' (imported as 'Link').

./components/Layout/Navbar.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'next/link' (imported as 'Link').

./components/Layout/Navbar.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'next/link' (imported as 'Link').

./components/Layout/Navbar.js
Attempted import error: 'Link' is not exported from 'next/link' (imported as 'Link').

> Build error occurred
> Error: Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in
> pages/login
> pages/signup

Answer (score 0):

You can try with,

Client-side transitions between routes can be enabled via the Link component exported by *next/link.*

```
import Link from 'next/link'
```